# Bind a swift variable to another one

Tags: swift, variables, bind, updates

I wanted to be able to **bind** a variable to a UILabel.
I tried to create some sort of timer and I wanted to make sure that every time a variable `counter` gets modified, then also the text in the label will be updated automatically without writing it explicitly.

I thought of using something like this:

```
var _counter: Double = 0.0 
    var counter: Double{
        get{
            return _counter;
        }

        set{
            timeLabel.text = String(newValue);
            _counter = newValue;
        }

}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best way (I also didn't managed to make it work this way).

What would you suggest to do?

Comment: Have you tried KVO? https://cocoacasts.com/key-value-observing-kvo-and-swift-3/

Comment: use swift bond: https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to make your code work, you can try this:

```
var _counter: Double = 0.0 {
       didSet{
       timeLabel.text = String("\(_counter)")
       //old values can be retrieved by calling print("\(oldValue)")
       }
}
```